# Choice between Pop OS and Linux Lite

Tags: boot, dual-boot, pop-os

I am using a decade old HP Pavilion g6 notebook. With Linux Lite installed up until last week and working well beyond my expectations, I decided to side install and have a taste of PopOS! too. All went well. However, when I now reboot my laptop, it never asks me to choose the available options and boots directly into PopOS! Linux Lite however is my OS of choice. I am looking to get a resolution to this.

I have tried updating the etc/default/grub file with what the other resources demonstrated, but to no avail.

I might not be surprised to find that the solution to my current query can be a very simple one but I think I am overwhelming myself looking here and there and also and of course I do not want to mess up with my system.

Please take some time out and let me know as to how can I get around this issue.

I reiterate, I want the option to select between the choice of OS I want to go with when I restart my laptop.

Please, please, please let me know if there's anything that might be added to the question to better help the resolution.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pop_OS! does not use `grub`; it uses `systemd-boot`. Which is why making changes to `grub` do not affect it.

Your best option is to hit the key that shows the boot menu (<kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, or similar) and select from there the OS you want to boot in to.